# PHP - getting user first name from mysql database (session.php)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show welcome message with user name. I have a session setted up, everything is working without errors, however I can't make user name appear next to "welcome". I read loads of posts, most of the suggestions were asking to add `session_start();` before `echo`. Still nothing..

Here is code for session.php if someone could help me:

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$conn = mysql_connect("**.***.***.***", "*********", "*********");
mysql_select_db("*********",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE user_name='" . $_POST["fname"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $row[user_id];
$_SESSION["fname"] = $row[user_name];
} else {
$message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}
if(isset($_SESSION["user_name"])) {
header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

And here is code for the profile page where user name should appear:

```
<?php
include('session.php'); //file shown above
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="profile">
<b id="welcome">Welcome : <i>

<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['fname'];
?>

</i></b>
<b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm just learning PHP and this is a basic test.

Thank You for any information.
Hava a nice day !

***UPDATE:***

loginscript.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$error='';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['uname']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{
$uname=$_POST['uname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$conn = mysql_connect("**.***.***.***", "*********", "*********");
$uname = stripslashes($uname);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($uname);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$db = mysql_select_db("*********", $conn);
$query = mysql_query("select * from WebsiteUsers where password='$password' AND uname='$uname'", $conn);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$uname;
header("location: profile.php");
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($conn);
}
}
?>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: show your session.php file. I have tested your code and it is running fine

Comment: Where the user logins in? Also there is a strange thing on your code here: `if(isset($_SESSION["user_name"]))` if the user_name is ON the session you redirect the user to the login page. It should be the other way around right? like `if(  !isset($_SESSION["user_name"]) )`

Comment: session.php is the first bit of code.

Comment: @user2387628 I have updated my answer for you. Let me know what you find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your array keys, for example you have:

> $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row[user_id];

But this should in fact be

```
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $row['user_id'];
```

Note the single quotes around the array key in `$row`. I see you use double quotes and I think there are minor differences but the point is, use quotes around array key strings. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317969/3536236 .

There also ***might*** be an issue that you set the value with double quotes and then call the value with single quotes --

```
$_SESSION["fname"] = $row['fname'];
print $_SESSION['fname'];
```

But that's just a theory there.

Further debugging:

```
Print_r($_SESSION); <== what does this give you after the values are set?
```

- Use MySQLi or PDO rather than MySQL_ as this is now ***deprecated*** and should no longer be used.
- Add `exit;` after your `header` relocation calls. Because the rest of the script will still execute before the relocation header call is run, so you need to tell the script to stop executing as soon as you reach the `header(location: )` point.
- Be consistent and have all single `'` or all double `"` quotes in your array key identifiers.
- **Remove** `session_start()` from inside your HTML, this function call **MUST** be at the very start/ top of the page, and nowhere else. You can replace this session_Start with the `print_r` referenced above, for debugging purposes.

### Debugging

First step, you need to enable errors on your page, so whatever page you're working on add this code to the top:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

This will output any errors the code fines to your browser when you run the page. Extremely useful and informative.

Next, I will show you the process you need to establish where in the logic chain the data is being "lost".

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE user_name='" . $_POST["fname"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");

print_r($result) <== should return something like "this is a type 4 element". False shows your DB is empty or your MySQL code is bad. 

$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);

var_dump($row) <== should return the values from the DB. It should also tell you what data type this variable is, as you demand an array, below:

if(is_array($row)) {
$_SESSION["UserID"] = $row[user_id];
$_SESSION["fname"] = $row[user_name];
} 
else {
die("This will display if the IF statement does not show TRUE.");
}
```

The `die` statement above would show you that the error is not in the session but more in your handling of the MySQL output,

I reaffirm you should *use single quotes on all your array keys everywhere*! Keep it consistent!!

Restructure your MySQL to be more this shape:

```
mysql_query($query) or print_r("line ".__LINE__.": ".mysql_error());
```

So that if there is any issue with your MySQL code it is found and shown to you. Much of programming is about finding where the error comes from, rather than the error itself.

Comment: Print_r($_SESSION); is giving me this :
Welcome : Array ( [login_user] => pkirst ) which seems to be ok as I used "pkirst" as my login.

Comment: @user2387628 ok so then that means the value is not being saved to the session infact, the code you posted doesn't have that session value in it, so where did `login_user` value get set?

Comment: @user2387628 change your double quote arrays to single quote arrays and then after the line setting `$result` do: `var_dump($row);` to see what data is actually returned from the MySQL

Comment: just checked all the files and I think it's from login.php 

<?php
include('loginscript.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: profile.php");
}
?> 
What should I change it to ? So sorry.. I'm new to PHP..

Comment: I changed it all however its not displaying any errors or info. does it matter if I login.php has session set to login_user?

Comment: @user2387628 no I was just confused where that value came from, but I then saw your updates. What you should do now is go through your code so that all array keys are wrapped in quotes (single or double), I think that's causing a hiccup for you.

Comment: got it!
by mistake I went from uname to fname. Changed it all and it's working now. Thank you so much! have a nice day mate.

Comment: @user2387628 awesome. Glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `session_start();` in the start of the `profile.php`

Comment: There is no need for that since he is including the session.php at the start of the file

Comment: Yes, If first block of code is session.php then no need to declare it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
$message="";
if(count($_POST)>0) {
$conn = mysql_connect("**.***.***.***", "*********", "*********");
mysql_select_db("*********",$conn);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers WHERE user_name='" .    $_POST["fname"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
 $row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $_SESSION["UserID"] = $row[user_id];
 $_SESSION["fname"] = $row[user_name];
 } else {
 $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
}
}
if($_SESSION["fname"]=="") {// changed from $_SESSION['user_name'],checks if sesison is empty , will redirect to login page.
 header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: first of all at the end where you have if statement session variable was undefined $_SESSION["user_name"]

Comment: Can you edit your answer and add this in? Answers with just code block are not very good at conveying the issue and solution. Cheers.

Comment: I tried your code but it still doesn't show user name. thanks

Comment: what you get as result , can you try to echo another session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    $db_result  = mysql_fetch_array($result); $row = $db_result[0];
```

instead of :

```
$row  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: can you dump $result and  $db_result?